# Getting a cookie, server side includes vs javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, ssi

```
<!--#if expr="$HTTP_COOKIE=/fonts\-loaded\=true/" -->
<html lang="en" class="fonts-loaded">
<!--#else -->
<html lang="en">
<!--#endif -->
```

vs

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script>
    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    if(getCookie('fonts-loaded'))
        document.documentElement.className += ' fonts-loaded';
    </script>
</head>
```

if I can't use the former. does executing the javascript in the head of the HTML have performance implication or in this situation the effect is negligible? or should I put it at the end of body tag and if so what the difference between putting javascript at the head tag or the end of the body tag?

I want to put .fonts-loaded class as soon as possible.

Comment: the only reason it's recommended to put it at the end of the body is so that the page can fully load before running the javascript. if your script doesnt need the page fully  loaded then its fine to put it in the head.

Comment: @Occam'sRazor make sense but doesn't block the page from rendering or resources like CSS from loading.

Comment: is that a question or what? I don't understand what you're trying to say. one little inline script won't block anything

Comment: @Occam'sRazor I know but more like when you cross the line and you should start putting stuff in the body even if it's not convenient. anyway I guess is just me being chatty, you hit the nail right on the head with your first comment. thanks, man.

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score -1):

It is best to put the javascript within the head tag rather than the body. This is only until the script starts to cause issues in the rendering of the page though.

Comment: it's generally better to put them in the body, but this is an exception